# postgresql coalesce

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone say why this select returns 3.0 instead of 3.5:

```
SELECT coalesce(1.0*(7/2),0) as foo
```

This one returns 3:

```
SELECT coalesce(7/2,0) as foo
```

I'm just trying to divide a SUM by COUNT to find an average. I need it 0 if null and 1 rounded by 1 decimal in case I have results.

Comment: not having access to postgres, but try `coalesce(7/2,0.0)` and see if that changes anything. sneaky suspicion it might be imposing int output since 0 is an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE((1.0 * 7)/2, 0) AS foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, [`7/2` is an integer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html), [`1.0` is numeric](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html), and so `1.0*(7/2)==1.0 * 3 == 3.0`.

Comment: sooo...how do I get 3.5 out of it I'm still unsure.

Comment: Would you submit that query result to your boss? :) You just reproduced 3.0 instead of 3.5 which is the right result. I read that `division (integer division truncates the result)` but how do you get a right division result in this situation?

Jack please submit your answer. It's the right one.

Comment: 0_o What do you mean by "the right result"? PostgreSQL has integer division. Other languages don't. If you need floating point division, cast appropriately.

Comment: @GigiContra - And just what do you mean by "would you submit that query result to your boss"?

Answer (score 0):

This feels better:

```
select 7.0/2.0;
--------------------
 3.5000000000000000
```